# Custom variable in Word document

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-office, microsoft-word-2013, microsoft-word-2016

I have a software manual in MS Word whose content (mainly text) changes slightly depending on some factors.

I'd like to do something like the following which uses Field codes:

```
{ IF manual_version = 1 "Some true text for version 1" "" \* MERGEFORMAT  \* MERGEFORMAT }
{ IF manual_version = 2 "Some true text for version 2" "" \* MERGEFORMAT  \* MERGEFORMAT }
{ IF manual_version = 3 "Some true text for version 3" "" \* MERGEFORMAT  \* MERGEFORMAT }
```

How do I add the variable "manual_version" and keep it hidden so it doesn't appear in the document?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [document variables](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/306281/how-to-store-and-retrieve-variables-in-word-documents). They are API-accessible only values, which can be included in the fields evaluation.

First, you have to use the API to insert the document variable. For example, open the Visual Basic editor (Developer -> Code -> Visual Basic, or just <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F11</kbd>) and add the following code:

```
Sub AddVariable()
    ActiveDocument.Variables.Add Name:="manual_version", Value:=1
End Sub
```

You can then execute it (for example with <kbd>F5</kbd>). This snippet will insert document variable `manual_version` with value of 1 and preserve it in the document.

Then, you can use this variable in the IF fields:

```
{ IF { DOCVARIABLE manual_version }= 1 "Some true text for version 1" "" }
```

Note that [DOCVARIABLE](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/docvariable-field-32a81e22-c5c1-4b16-8097-f0de851db67c) is again a field, nested in the [IF field](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/if-field-9f79e82f-e53b-4ff5-9d2c-ae3b22b7eb5e).